# Google drive multiselect stack view

Tags: android, animation, swipe, stackview

How to create a view that is stacked on multi-select with animations like in google drive app?
I have found some libraries that provide tinder swipe like view but i am wondering if this is the right way to go. In Drive app on selection there is animation that places the selected item to the bottom of the stack and dismiss the selection if you swipe the stacked view right or left. Is this custom behavior or there is some library that provides this?

[image]

Comment: Any luck with this? I too am interesting in something like this. I'm surprised it's not a stock Android pattern.

Comment: No, i had to make custom views and stack them one above the other, its tricky to do it right...